# Localization on Firefox Addon Doesn't get Updated on next creation of xpi file

Tags: localization, firefox-addon, mozilla

I am developing a firefox addon and localizing(l10n) the same. When I add/change any keys(localized text) in my addon and create a new xpi file using the jpm tool. On Installing the new xpi of the addon , the key is only displayed on the addon. And for the modifications of the l10n value the new value is not displayed. It uses the old value. The new value for the key is not updated in the newly created addon.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

During development, load your l10n file with `'?' + Math.random()` tagged onto the end. This avoids the caching problem you are seeing. when it comes time to release, then make it `?someConstantLikeVersion#.#` so it will cache that file.